# Adicionar una ventana modal para confirmacion ajax

Tags: php, ajax

este es mi codigo funciona bien pero ejecuta la acción directamente.. como puedo adicionar una ventana modal que me permita cancelar o aceptar la acción.

```
<td>
 <a class="btn btn-sm btn-success" href="#" data-role="update" data-usuario="<? 
 php echo $mostrar['usuario'] ;?>">Activar</a>
</td>
```

llamada a la función

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  $(document).ready(function(){
      activaUsuario();
  });
</script>
```

codigo de la funcion en funciones.js

```
function activaUsuario(){

    $(document).on('click','a[data-role=update]',function(){

    alert($(this).data('usuario'));
    var a = $(this).data("usuario");

      $.ajax({
        type:"POST",
        url:"process",
        data:"process=1&usuario=" + a,

        success: function(){
                alert("Actualizado con exito.");
         }
      }) 
  });
}
```

estoy probando con el modal de bootstrap.. obtengo la variable en la modal con la linea var a = $(this).data("usuario"); pero como paso esa variable a ajax y se pueda usar en $('#aceptar').click(function(){ .... que es el boton de aceptar del modal. no lo toma me sale object undefined.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Para lograr obtener el `data-usuarios` deber usar la función `attr` de `jquery` puedes [leer la documentación](https://api.jquery.com/attr/#attr-attributeName) , aquí te muestro un ejemplo de como usarla.

```
$(element).attr('data-user')
```

Para este caso tengo la tabla de usuarios, tiene un botón activar con atributo `data-user`, al dar click consulto este atributo y lo paso al botón **si** del modal ,del cual obtendré el `idUser` para pasar a la función ajax. ( agregue un función especial para simular la espera de la petición).

```js
var deafultMessage = "¡Seguro deseas activar este usuario?"

function showActivar(element){
  let idUser = $(element).attr('data-user')
  $('#js_activar').attr('data-user',idUser)
  $('#exampleModal').modal('show')
  console.log(idUser)
}

function sendActivar(element){
   let idUser = $(element).attr('data-user')
   // aqui abajo tu funciona ajax
   // ajax.
   //  .done
   // mira como paso el id a esta otra funcion opcioanl
   optinalFunction(idUser);
 
}

function optinalFunction(idUser){
   $('#js_message').text("Activando... ID:"+idUser)
   setTimeout(()=>{
     $('#js_message').text("ACTIVADO CON EXITO!!!")
     setTimeout(()=>{
        $('#js_message').text(deafultMessage)
        $('#exampleModal').modal('hide')
     },1000)
   },2000)
}
```

```html
<!-- LIBRERIAS PARA MODAL CON BOOSTRAP -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-ggOyR0iXCbMQv3Xipma34MD+dH/1fQ784/j6cY/iJTQUOhcWr7x9JvoRxT2MZw1T" crossorigin="anonymous">
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-q8i/X+965DzO0rT7abK41JStQIAqVgRVzpbzo5smXKp4YfRvH+8abtTE1Pi6jizo" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.7/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-UO2eT0CpHqdSJQ6hJty5KVphtPhzWj9WO1clHTMGa3JDZwrnQq4sF86dIHNDz0W1" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-JjSmVgyd0p3pXB1rRibZUAYoIIy6OrQ6VrjIEaFf/nJGzIxFDsf4x0xIM+B07jRM" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

<!-- USUARIO -->
<table>
<tr>
 <td>USER 1<td>
 <td><button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" onclick="showActivar(this)" data-user="1" >Activar</button><td>
</tr>
<tr>
 <td>USER 2<td>
 <td><button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" onclick="showActivar(this)" data-user="2" >Activar</button><td>
</tr>
</table>



<div class="modal fade" id="exampleModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="exampleModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
  <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
    <div class="modal-content">
     <div class="modal-header">
        <h5 class="modal-title" id="js_message">¡Seguro deseas activar este usuario?</h5>
     </div>
     <div class="modal-footer">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" data-dismiss="modal">No, sacame de aquí</button>
        <button id="js_activar" data-user="" type="button" class="btn btn-primary" onclick="sendActivar(this)">Sí, mi querido Watson</button>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: me sirvió tu respuesta... pero como seria si tengo que pasarle 2 atributos como data-user y data-code. en la funcion showActivar(this) me lleva los 2 atributos pero para regresarlos al modal como haria si el id es unico js_activar, solo recibo el atributo de regreso  $('#js_activar').attr('data-user',idUser)..

Comment: agregar otro elemento data al <button id="js_activas"> siendo `$('#js_activar').attr('data-user',idUser)` y `$('#js_activar').attr('data-code',userCode)`

Comment: si lo hize asi pero como los devuelvo del java al modal.. ambos data-user y data-code entran al id="js_activar" ???    $('#js_activar').attr('data-user',idUser) y $('#js_activar').attr('data-code',userCode)   me seria de ayuda .. ya que solo lo tengo con confirm de java directo sin usar el modal.